# Seeking short story about the last of a species of thousand foot trees

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the 1970s I read a story about the last of a species of thousand foot trees on a planet, being harvested for building material.  There are several "last tree" books and stories written since but I cannot find this one.  Any historians out there who recall this one?

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In the 1970s I read a story**

You may be thinking of [Robert F. Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_F._Young)'s 1959 novelette ["To Fell a Tree"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74436), which was also the answer to the old question [Huge tree, last of kind, being cut down. Logger meets female tree-spirit who is dying as her tree is cut down](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174362/huge-tree-last-of-kind-being-cut-down-logger-meets-female-tree-spirit-who-is). It was first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, July 1959](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61166+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v017n01_1959-07_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v017n01_1959-07_PDF#page/n3/mode/2up). You might have read it in the anthology [*A Decade of Fantasy and Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?459) ([Robert P. Mills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_P._Mills), ed.) which went through [several editions](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?36296).

**about the last of a species of thousand foot trees on a planet,**

> All during the voyage in from Earth and all during the ride from the spaceport to the village, they had tossed the joke back and forth. There was—if you took credence in Suhre's and Blueskies' and Wright's talk . . . and in his own talk too—at least one dryad living in the last giant tree on Omicron Ceti 18, and what a time they were going to have catching her!
>
> [. . . .]
>
> The saddle-rope hung down like a silvery liana from the lofty crotch of his choosing, swayed gently in the morning breeze. The crotch was about twenty feet below the highest point of the tree, or over a thousand feet from the ground.
>
> The figure was hard to assimilate. He had climbed a good many tall trees; some of them had even run as high as five hundred feet. But this one made them seem insignificant. This one was over a thousand feet high.
>
> A *thousand* feet! . . .

**being harvested for building material.**

> In a way the tree would be a harvest in itself, for wood was dear on Omicron Ceti 18—almost as dear as it was on Earth. But they wouldn't be getting it for nothing, Strong thought; not if you figured the goodly sum they were going to have to shell out to Tree Killers, Inc. for the tree's removal.

Comment: Youngs "to fell a tree" is correct, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! This was one of those haunting memories from adolescence.  I've tracked down several others but this one eluded me.   The Sun Grows Cold, Star Kings, and Tunnel in the Sky were some others, if those mean anything.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Not familiar with *The Sun Grows Cold*, the other two are Hamilton and Heinlein. If you have any more unsolved story-ID mysteries, bring them here!