# 1970s-80s SF short story about a logger sent to a planet to fell the biggest tree

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

May have been in *Astounding/Analog*. The logger meets the spirit of the tree, cuts it down anyway -then all the houses of the village at its base begin crumbling.  The tree had grown them for the people of the planet.

Answer (score 5):

["To Fell a Tree"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?74436), a novelette by [Robert F. Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_F._Young), also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174362/huge-tree-last-of-kind-being-cut-down-logger-meets-female-tree-spirit-who-is) and [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188661/seeking-short-story-about-the-last-of-a-species-of-thousand-foot-trees); first published in [*The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction*, July 1959](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?61166+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v017n01_1959-07_PDF/Fantasy__Science_Fiction_v017n01_1959-07_PDF#page/n3/mode/1up).

**SF short story about a logger sent to a planet to fell the biggest tree**

> All during the voyage in from Earth and all during the ride from the spaceport to the village, they had tossed the joke back and forth. There was—if you took credence in Suhre's and Blueskies' and Wright's talk . . . and in his own talk too—at least one dryad living in the last giant tree on Omicron Ceti 18, and what a time they were going to have catching her!

**The logger meets the spirit of the tree,**

> What did a dryad do, he wondered, when her tree died?
>
> *She dies, too,* she answered, before he had a chance to ask.
>
> *But why?*
>
> *You wouldn't understand.*

**cuts it down anyway—**

> There was the prolonged swishing sound of the descent; the thick and thunderous sound of the descent's end; the quick brief trembling of the earth . . .
>
> The surface of the massive stump grew bright red in the sunlight. Strong let the cutter fall to the ground. He circled the stump, stumbling now and then, till he came to the building-high length of the fallen stub. It had dropped just as he had wanted it to, its uppermost section landing neatly between two of the rows of houses. But he did not care about the houses any more. He had never cared about them really. He continued walking, gazing steadfastly at the ground. He found her presently, near the edge of the square. He had known he would find her if he looked hard enough. She was sunlight and meadow flower, a translucent pattern of grass. He could not see all of her—only her waist and breasts and arms and lovely dying face. The rest of her was crushed beneath the stub: her legs, her small, leaf-sandaled feet—
>
> "Forgive me," he said, and saw her smile and nod her head, and saw her die; and the grass came back, and the meadow flower, and the sun.

**—then all the houses of the village at its base begin crumbling.**

> "I killed her inch by inch, foot by foot. I cut her down arm by arm, leg by leg. I *murdered* her!" Strong paused. Something was wrong. Something that should have happened had failed to happen. Then he saw the mayor staring at his fist and he realized what the wrongness was.
>
> When his fist had struck the bar, he should have felt pain. He had not. He saw why: his fist had not rebounded from the wood—it had sunk into the wood. It was as though the wood were rotten.
>
> He raised his fist slowly. A decayed smell arose from the ragged dent it had made. The wood *was* rotten.

**The tree had grown them for the people of the planet.**

> His laughter died. He took a deep breath, expelled it. "But don't you see it, Wright? The tree? The village? What does a species of tree capable of growing to that size need to perpetuate its growth and to maintain itself after it has attained its growth? Nourishment. Tons and tons of nourishment. And what kind of soil! Soil enriched by the wastes and the dead bodies, and irrigated by the artificial lakes and reservoirs that only a large community of human beings can provide.
>
> "So what does such a species of tree do? Over a period of centuries, maybe even millennia, it learns how to lure human beings to its side. How? By growing houses. That's right. By growing houses right out of its roots, lovely houses that human beings can't resist living in. You see it now, don't you, Wright? You see now, don't you, why the crude sap carried more nutrients than the tree needed, why the elaborated sap was so rich in oxygen and carbohydrates. The tree was trying to sustain more than just itself; it was trying to sustain the village, too. But it couldn't any longer—thanks to the eternal selfishness and the eternal stupidity of man."